# Getting all nested items from all values from Hashmp

Tags: java, parameters, hashmap

I used HashMap with the key as a string and values as an `ArrayList`:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Student>> students;
```

How do I get back *all* the `Student`  objects, that is, all the elements of all the `ArrayList` objects?

Comment: You mean `students.get(key)`?

Comment: no, i want entire list of Students from HashMap

Comment: you mean whole list?

Comment: So you want to combine all ArrayLists in your HashMap into one ArrayList?

Comment: yes i want whole list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want all the `Student`s, you can `Stream` over the `values()` of the `Map` and flatten the `Stream` with `flatMap`:

```
List<Students> studentList = students.values() // Collection<ArrayList<Students>>
                                     .stream() // Stream<ArrayList<Students>>
                                     .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<Students>
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you can't use Java 8, you'll have to iterate over the `values()` of the `Map` and add all of them to a `List`:

```
List<Students> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
for (ArrayList<Students> list : students.values())
    studentList.addAll(list);
```

Comment: Note: For java 8, if you are on some legacy system which is running on an older version, this won't work.

Comment: @Query I added an alternative for Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Students> studentList = students.get("stringKey");
```

If you want to get all the student lists.

Declare a separate array list and use `addAll()` method.

```
for (String key : studentList .keySet()) {
       finalList.addAll(studentList.get(key));
}
```

Comment: i want it for all Keys not like with specific key

Comment: @Query that's how it can be done or the way Eran has answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `values()` function to get all the `ArrayLists` in the students map to a single `Collection` object. Then we can convert the collection to an ArrayList by following approach.

```
Collection<ArrayList<Students>> studentCollection = students.values();
List<Students> studentList = new ArrayList<Students>(studentCollection);
```